# How to access collection results in best way?

Tags: plone

I'm trying to render collection result in some of pages. What I understand is I cant render below page template code outside collection folder context as its gives attributes error (I did use context.collection-id.getCatalog()). Any idea or pointer is useful.

results.pt

```
<tal:block repeat="objectItem python:context.queryCatalog()" >
  <a tal:attributes="href objectItem/getURL" ><tal:title content="objectItem/Title" />       </a><br/>
   <tal:block tal:define="obj objectItem/getObject;" >
          <tal:block content="structure obj/text/output" />
   </tal:block>
```

But

if I do something like below form outside of collection folder context then its working fine.

```
 <tal:block tal:content="structure context/collection-id/results" />
```

results is page template inside collection folder which is having above mention code.

Comment: What is collection-id ? If it's the id of your collection, you can't do this. you can do something like python:getattr(context, 'collection-id') to get your collection object

Comment: you should have put this as answer and I would have acceoted it as this is one step closer to what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `context` with a reference to your Collection:

```
<tal:block repeat="objectItem context/collection-id/queryCatalog">
```

There is nothing magical about the queryCatalog method, but you do need to call it on the Collection instance itself, not on an arbitrary context. :-)